# How to create YAML file from data listed in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ruamel.yaml

I have a file hostname.txt contain the following:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Would like below format in hostname.yaml file, preferably using python (bash shell will also do).

```
host1:
  hostname: 1.1.1.1
  platform: linux

host2:
  hostname: 2.2.2.2
  platform: linux

host3:
  hostname: 3.3.3.3
  platform: linux
```

Comment: Welcome! Are you able to share examples of what you have tried already?

Comment: Why are you not using the third value (`3.3.3.3`) in your input file? Is there any reason this is tagged pyyaml? That library only supports part of YAML 1.1., outdated over 10 years ago.

Comment: @Anthon, I have updated the 3rd value to 3.3.3.3 (apologies for the confusion). No specific reason for tagging pyyaml, thanks for the info and looking into this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since YAML files are text files, you can in principle write these with the standard 
Python output routines. However, you would need to know all details of 
the [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) in order to make this a valid YAML file.

That is relatively simple for your example, but that is just because you did
not hit any YAML specials that would e.g. would require quoting.

Lacking detailed knowledge of the YAML specification it is best to
stick with a YAML loader/dumper library. The one library supporting
the YAML 1.2 standard is ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of
that package).

With that installed (using `pip install ruamel.yaml` in your Python virtual environment), you can do:

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('hostname.txt')
out_file = in_file.with_suffix('.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = {}
index = 0
for line in in_file.open():
    line = line.strip()
    index += 1
    data[f'host{index}'] = dict(hostname=line, platform='linux')

yaml.dump(data, out_file)
```

which gives:

```
host1:
  hostname: 1.1.1.1
  platform: linux
host2:
  hostname: 2.2.2.2
  platform: linux
host3:
  hostname: 3.3.3.3
  platform: linux
```

Please note that hte hostname (IP address?) for the third entry differs from your example, 
as I had no idea how you want your program to repeat the second value and not use the 
third value in the input file.

Comment: Tested the script today and it works. Thanks Anthon!

Comment: @JON If this answer solves your problem, please consider *accepting* it by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved, without reading the comments. It also changes the appearance of the question and this answer in lists. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that all plateforms are 'linux', as you don't give additional details about that. So you may obtain the final result quite straightforwardly by looping over hosts:

```
hosts = ('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3')

pattern = "host%s:\n  hostname: %s\n  plateform: linux\n"

yaml = "\n".join(pattern % (n+1, host) for (n, host) in enumerate(hosts))

print(yaml)
```

result:

```
host1:
  hostname: 1.1.1.1
  plateform: linux

host2:
  hostname: 2.2.2.2
  plateform: linux

host3:
  hostname: 3.3.3.3
  plateform: linux
```

Comment: Thanks for looking on this query. I tried running the script on Ubuntu 16, however, encounter an error "syntax error near unexpected token `(' ". I will try fixing the error and will update once able to run the script. Here is the link of my initial test: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jHaTgXFWMVLQnFf8aTdaxDYjUWub8bXhV3NsejUSvlM/edit?usp=sharing . Btw, the script should open the file containing the list of hosts and not inline (may contain hundred of host). Also, which platform you tested it?

Comment: @JON : I check the link you provided. According to the name you used (.sh), you tested my script as a bash script, but it is a Python script, so you have to test it with a Python interpreter

Comment: Confirmed working on python interpreter, thanks sciroccorics!